# Resize width of UITableView in didSelectRowAtIndexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

First selection not working but after second selection its working in iOS. Initially its not resize the width of `UITableView`. I need to resize the width in runtime.

Here is my `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    self.table.frame=CGRectMake(10, 162, 240, 854);//Actual width is 580 resize as 240}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may using -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath delegate method.Could you please cross check is it  'didSelectRowAtIndexPath:' or 'didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: you should take look on @albin Joseph comment, It's exactly matching to your issue

Comment: Its is didselect method only. Thank you

Comment: so what is the output happening ? What is wrong?Remove `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods

Comment: Initially app launches, first click of the row cant resize the width. after that second and third click it works fine @LithuT.V

Comment: Why first click of row selection wont resize the uitableview

Answer (score 0):

you have to call realoddata method of UITableView, so that it reflect the changes of table width
forexample

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [tableView beginUpdates]; NSLog(@"did select"); //resizing the width   
    self.table.frame=CGRectMake(10, 162, 240, 854); NSLog(@"did select"); 
    [tableView endUpdates]; 
    [tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: hattimarethanks you. i tried that too. but its not working in first selection of row after 2nd and 3 rd selcetion of rows its working fine.

Comment: I struck with this in last three days.

Comment: tableview is in UIviewcontroller?? or it is UItableviewcontroller??

Comment: Is is in UIviewController

Answer (score -1):

Try this in didSelect method :

```
  [yourTable reloadData];
```

Comment: when i use [table reloadData]; UITABLEVIEW WIDTH not change even second selection of row. Thank you.